Password reset not working in laravel with filament php
I've enabled authentication in the AdminPanelProvider like so:
return $panel
            ->registration(Register::class)
            ->emailVerification()
            ->passwordReset()
            ->emailVerification()
            ->profile()
            ->login()

I'm using mailtrap for local development, and everything works, except for passwordReset. When I provide an email to reset a password I don't receive an email in mailtrap. I'm I missing something else in the implementation?

did you set configs on the .env file?

It's because the QUEUE_CONNECTION is database in the .env file. Running the queue or using sync connection instead of database fixes the problem.

As a reference: https://github.com/filamentphp/filament/issues/11995
